# Why is my FileUpload doing nothing?

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload

I have an ASP.NET/C# program which is trying to upload a file:

```
try
{
    upload.SaveAs(theFileName);
    Utils.MsgBox("File successfully uploaded to " + inputFileName+". Select which sheet to use and click the button beneath.");

}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    Utils.MsgBox(ex.ToString());
}
```

The program is reaching this point, but not displaying the message after the upload. Neither is triggering the Catch Exception clause. The file has not been uploaded in the relevant folder, and I can find no errors in the Event Viewer that might give me a clue as to what is happening.

Why is it doing nothing?

Comment: are you using update panels??

Comment: No , I am not using Update panels.

Comment: Don't worry about Utils, that bit works.

Comment: i think there is nothing in the code which should not work...May be check file path by `Response.Write(theFileName);`

Comment: That's what I thought. I have already checked the filepath further up. I am guessing it is to do with permissions, but you would think it would tell me.

Comment: What is the content of `theFileName`?

Comment: If I do if (File.Exists(theFileName)) on an existing file, it works, so the filestring is OK

Comment: @SteveStaple , make a note that, theFileName should point to `D:\example\file.ext` ( just an example)

Comment: It was a permissions issue. Giving the IIIUser write permissions solved the problem, but it does not explain why I got no exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a permissions issue. Giving the IIS User write permissions solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

To get the file to be sent you might need to set the `enctype` property in the `form` to the value `"multipart/form-data"`

```
<form runat="server" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
... 
</form>
```